# Strange rj11 adapter from my ISP

Tags: networking, router, phone

I want to upgrade my current network, and when I was looking what I had at home I found this, provided by ISP, that connects my house to the ethernet…

[image]

Is there any way to change that to an rj45 output?
Currently I'm using rj11 cable to my modem.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

> I found this prvided by ISP

This looks very much like a [frequency filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSL_filter), otherwise known as a POTS splitter<sup>1</sup>, used for DSL connections. It's fully passive and does not change the actual signal in any way – all it does is prevent the DSL signal from reaching your analog phone (without the filter, you would hear it as noise).

<sup>1</sup> *POTS = Plain Old Telephone Service*

> Is there any way to change that to an rj45 output?

Only by using a modem. You cannot just rewire it directly, because it carries different kind of electrical signals than Ethernet (and those signals carry differently formatted data too) – you need to use a DSL modem to perform the conversion.

If you want to use your own router, then it should be possible to configure the modem to directly bridge the DSL connection to Ethernet. This is more difficult if the ISP uses PPPoA, but should be very easy if your ISP uses IPoE / PPPoE (which I believe is always the case with VDSL).

Comment: I think the intended functionality is the other way around, the DSL signal is protected from analog phone interference.

Comment: You *can* get POTS splitters with Ethernet RJ45 - but that won't help if the line & ISP are set up to expect an RJ11. (Just to prevent the OP from buying one & it failing to work;) You should actually ask your phone company/ISP what options they can provide for that socket. Different companies use different methods. The POTS splitter is usually provided with the modem/router as part of the setup package.

Comment: @DanielB: Possibly that too, but I've been told that newer modems already have a filter built-in, so having an external one isn't exactly necessary anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @DanielB: (Our own phone line had been Y-split and connected to two telephones on different floors long before DSL, so when an ADSL modem was finally connected, it wasn't through a single filter but _two_: one next to the telephone on floor 1, another next to the modem on floor 2. This way, removing the 2nd filter meant that the modem received both the DSL signal _and_ the analog voice signal. But whenever I did that, newer modems didn't even notice – they just kept working through calls and all.)